# How to use My Tailwind Color Pallet as Type

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

I'm creating a Component Badge on My Next 13 App, and I would like to have autocomplete for colors on it.

Is there a way to use my Tailwind Color Pallet as Type ?

Something like that:

```
import React from 'react'

type BadgeProps = {
  text: string
  color: // Tailwind Color Type
}

export const Badge = ({ text, color }: BadgeProps) => {
  return (
    <div
      className={`flex items-center justify-center p-4 text-center ${color}`}
    >
      {text}
    </div>
  )
}
```

I know a way to fix that but I'm gonna just use Classname as Props for this component

Comment: You can do `type Color = 'blue-100' | 'yellow-100' //colors you want to support`

Comment: I recently wrote a detailed explanation to a similar problem. Might wanna check it out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77521343/2438494