# Is there a way to select the brightness of a color from a palette based on just the color name in tailwind?

Tags: next.js, colors, tailwind-css

I'm trying to make a button with different variants, but I'm interested in whether there is a possibility to just determine which color will be used, and for the default classes to be only which color brightness will be used from the palette

for example, as the default value of the text, I want to set it to text-white, and if the button is an outline, then to take text-500, the brightness of a certain color in the variant

```
const buttonVariants = cva(
  "border-500 bg-500 text-white",
  {
    variants: {
      variant: {
        primary: "color-primary",
        secondary: "color-secondary",
      },
      outline: {
        true: "text-500"
      },
      size: {
        sm: "px-3",
        md: "px-4",
        lg: "px-8",
      },
    },
    defaultVariants: {
      variant: "primary",
      size: "md",
    },
  }
)
```

and in config I have just inherited default tailwind color palete

```
colors: {
  primary: colors.sky,
  secondary: colors.slate,
  info: colors.blue,
  success: colors.green,
  warning: colors.yellow,
  danger: colors.red,
}
```

I was thinking if there was any function based on which it could be done, but I couldn't find anything similar on the internet

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done. I in fact also did it in one of my projects.

Keep in mind that Tailwind only includes classes in your styles that you actively use. Building them from strings (e.g. `text-${color}/${opacity}`) will not work.

But you can access theme variables in your CSS using [arbitrary values](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#using-arbitrary-values), map them to [custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) and then use those properties in your component(s).

#### Arbitrary Values

First, define your custom properties (e.g. `--color-50, ..., --color-950`) and map them to tailwind variables using [arbitrary values](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#using-arbitrary-values) or CSS.

Inside your component you can then use those new variables leveraging arbitry values again:
`class="bg-[color:var(--color-400)] hover:bg-[color:var(--color-500)]"`

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>


<!--
  first you need to define custom variables that you can then use inside your button component (I just called dem "--color-x")
  ideally you would make your "variant" prop change these classes
-->
<div class="
  [--color-50:theme(colors.yellow.50)]
  [--color-100:theme(colors.yellow.100)]
  [--color-200:theme(colors.yellow.200)]
  [--color-300:theme(colors.yellow.300)]
  [--color-400:theme(colors.yellow.400)]
  [--color-500:theme(colors.yellow.500)]
  [--color-600:theme(colors.yellow.600)]
  [--color-700:theme(colors.yellow.700)]
  [--color-800:theme(colors.yellow.800)]
  [--color-900:theme(colors.yellow.900)]
  [--color-950:theme(colors.yellow.950)]
">
  <!-- implement the button using these new variables -->
  <button class="bg-[color:var(--color-400)] text-white hover:bg-[color:var(--color-600)]">
    Primary button
  </button>
</div>

<div class="
  [--color-50:theme(colors.blue.50)]
  [--color-100:theme(colors.blue.100)]
  [--color-200:theme(colors.blue.200)]
  [--color-300:theme(colors.blue.300)]
  [--color-400:theme(colors.blue.400)]
  [--color-500:theme(colors.blue.500)]
  [--color-600:theme(colors.blue.600)]
  [--color-700:theme(colors.blue.700)]
  [--color-800:theme(colors.blue.800)]
  [--color-900:theme(colors.blue.900)]
  [--color-950:theme(colors.blue.950)]
">
  <!-- note that the implementation of the button is exactly the same -->
  <button class="bg-[color:var(--color-400)] text-white hover:bg-[color:var(--color-600)]">
    Secondary button
  </button>
</div>
```

#### Custom CSS Classes for reusability

To make things easier and more reusable you could instead define custom "recolor" classes in your CSS and use them on every component that supports recoloring like so:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<style type="text/tailwindcss">
:root {
  /* default to primary (yellow is my primary in this example) */
  --color-50: theme(colors.yellow.50);
  --color-100: theme(colors.yellow.100);
  --color-200: theme(colors.yellow.200);
  --color-300: theme(colors.yellow.300);
  --color-400: theme(colors.yellow.400);
  --color-500: theme(colors.yellow.500);
  --color-600: theme(colors.yellow.600);
  --color-700: theme(colors.yellow.700);
  --color-800: theme(colors.yellow.800);
  --color-900: theme(colors.yellow.900);
  --color-950: theme(colors.yellow.950);
}

.recolor-primary {
  --color-50: theme(colors.yellow.50);
  --color-100: theme(colors.yellow.100);
  --color-200: theme(colors.yellow.200);
  --color-300: theme(colors.yellow.300);
  --color-400: theme(colors.yellow.400);
  --color-500: theme(colors.yellow.500);
  --color-600: theme(colors.yellow.600);
  --color-700: theme(colors.yellow.700);
  --color-800: theme(colors.yellow.800);
  --color-900: theme(colors.yellow.900);
  --color-950: theme(colors.yellow.950);
}

.recolor-secondary {
  --color-50: theme(colors.blue.50);
  --color-100: theme(colors.blue.100);
  --color-200: theme(colors.blue.200);
  --color-300: theme(colors.blue.300);
  --color-400: theme(colors.blue.400);
  --color-500: theme(colors.blue.500);
  --color-600: theme(colors.blue.600);
  --color-700: theme(colors.blue.700);
  --color-800: theme(colors.blue.800);
  --color-900: theme(colors.blue.900);
  --color-950: theme(colors.blue.950);
}
</style>

<!-- the "recolor-x" class should be added to your component based on the "variant" prop --> 

<button class="recolor-primary bg-[color:var(--color-400)] text-white hover:bg-[color:var(--color-600)]">
    Primary button
</button>

<button class="recolor-secondary bg-[color:var(--color-400)] text-white hover:bg-[color:var(--color-600)]">
    Secondary button
</button>
```

#### Final Thoughts

You might also want to define a contrast color variable – using the same approach – for each color. This allows you to switch the text color automatically for a11y.

```css
.recolor-primary {
  --color-200: theme(colors.yellow.200);
  --color-200-contrast: theme(colors.black);
  --color-600: theme(colors.yellow.600);
  --color-600-contrast: theme(colors.white);
}
```

```html
<button class="recolor-primary bg-[color:var(--color-200)] text-[color:var(--color-200-contrast)] hover:bg-[color:var(--color-600)] hover:text-[color:var(--color-600-contrast)]">
  A primary button that changes text color as well as bg color
<button>
```

To make things even more reusable you could create your own tailwind "auto" color, that allows you to write classes like `bg-auto-500` instead of `bg-[color:var(--color-400)]`.
Check out my [Tailwind playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/nLbofzWS9l) for a working example.

#### Back to your exmaple

Your example could be implemented like this, given that you implemented the `recolor-x` classes as in the tailwind example before.

```js
const buttonVariants = cva(
  "", // no common classes
  {
    variants: {
      variant: {
        primary: "recolor-primary",
        secondary: "recolor-secondary",
      },
      outline: {
        // bg-transparent could cause problems depending on parent background color
        true: "border-auto-500 text-auto-500 bg-transparent",
        false: "bg-auto-500 text-auto-contrast-500",
      },
      size: {
        sm: "px-3",
        md: "px-4",
        lg: "px-8",
      },
    },
    defaultVariants: {
      variant: "primary",
      size: "md",
    },
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Whitespace your answer helped me a lot, I made some small changes to reduce the code,

I added a plugin in tailwind config for automatic generation of variables inside classes

maybe it will be easier for you on the next project to use it like this because everything is inside the tailwind config

#### Import this in tailwind config

```
const plugin = require('tailwindcss/plugin')
```

#### Extend colors with this

```
auto: Object.fromEntries([50, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 950].map((value) => [value, `var(--color-${value}, ${colors.sky[value]})`])),
```

This will be default color `colors.sky[value]`

#### Plugin

```
 plugins: [
    plugin(({ theme, addUtilities }) => {
      const autoColors = {};
      const colors = theme('colors');
      
      for (const color in colors) {
        if (typeof colors[color] === 'object') {
          const colorPalette = {};

          for (const colorInner in colors[color]) {
            colorPalette[`--color-${colorInner}`] = colors[color][colorInner];
          }

          autoColors[`.color-${color}`] = colorPalette;
        }
      }
    
      addUtilities(autoColors, ['responsive', 'hover']);
    })
  ],
```

#### Usage

```
<div class="color-primary text-auto-600">Text</div>
```

#### Update to support alpha values

```
auto: Object.fromEntries([50, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 950].map((value) => [value, `rgba(var(--color-${value}), <alpha-value>)`])),
```

.

```
plugin(({ theme, addUtilities }) => {
  const autoColors = {};
  const colors = theme('colors');

  const hexToRgb = (hex) => {
    let fullHex = hex;
    
    // Convert #RGB to #RRGGBB format
    if (hex.length === 4) {
      fullHex = `#${hex[1]}${hex[1]}${hex[2]}${hex[2]}${hex[3]}${hex[3]}`;
    }

    // Function to convert hex to RGB
    const bigint = parseInt(fullHex.slice(1), 16);
    const r = (bigint >> 16) & 255;
    const g = (bigint >> 8) & 255;
    const b = bigint & 255;
    return [r, g, b].join(', ');
  };
  
  for (const color in colors) {
    if (typeof colors[color] === 'object') {
      const colorPalette = {};

      for (const colorInner in colors[color]) {
        const hexValue = colors[color][colorInner];
        const rgbValue = hexToRgb(hexValue);
        colorPalette[`--color-${colorInner}`] = rgbValue;
      }

      autoColors[`.color-${color}`] = colorPalette;
    }
  }

  addUtilities(autoColors, ['responsive', 'hover']);
})
```